# Adding ComboBoxItem to a ComboBox inside a UserControl (XAML/WPF)

Tags: wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls

I need to populate the `ComboBox` inside `ucComboBox` in the main Window (by using `ComboBoxItem` inside xaml code) but I get these 2 errors:

1. The object `ucComboBox` already has a child and cannot add `ComboBoxItem`. `ucComboBox` can accept only one child.
2. The property `Content` can only be set once.

There is no complete answer in this question
"[Adding ComboBoxItem to a combobox inside a user control (XAML/WPF)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785133/adding-comboboxitem-to-a-combobox-inside-a-user-control-xaml-wpf)"

```
<Window x:Class="CustomComboBox.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CustomComboBox"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="40" />
        <RowDefinition Height="40" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ComboBox Grid.Row="0">
        <ComboBoxItem>Male</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Female</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>

    <local:ucComboBox Grid.Row="1">
        <ComboBoxItem>Male</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Female</ComboBoxItem>
    </local:ucComboBox>
</Grid>
```

```
<UserControl x:Class="CustomComboBox.ucComboBox"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CustomComboBox"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="30" d:DesignWidth="100">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ComboBox Grid.Row="0">
    </ComboBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: What's the point of having `ucComboBox` at all, when there is nothing except a ComboBox inside? Why not create a derived ComboBox?

Comment: It's not just a UserControl with a ComboBox inside. I tried to explain my problem as simple as possible and remove all the unrelated things.

Answer (score 0):

`ucComboBox` **is not** a `ComboBox`. It **has** a `ComboBox`. It is a `UserControl`. So that you cannot add any `ComboBoxItem` to its content.

An idea is to inherit `ucComboBox` from `ComboBox`. And, instead of using `Content` of `ucComboBox`, use `Items`.

*PS*: "[Adding ComboBoxItem to a combobox inside a user control (XAML/WPF)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785133/adding-comboboxitem-to-a-combobox-inside-a-user-control-xaml-wpf)" is not your answer.

Best wishes.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my problem. Here is the code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="CustomComboBox.ucComboBox"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CustomComboBox"
         Loaded="UserControl_Loaded"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="50" d:DesignWidth="300">

<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">User Control</Label>
    <ComboBox Name="cmb" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" >
    </ComboBox>
</Grid>
```

```
    public partial class ucComboBox : UserControl
{
    public ucComboBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        cmb.ItemsSource = ValueList;
    }

    public List<ComboBoxItem> ValueList
    {
        get { return (List<ComboBoxItem>)GetValue(ValueListProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValueListProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ValueList.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueListProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ValueList", typeof(List<ComboBoxItem>), typeof(ucComboBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new List<ComboBoxItem>(), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender, new PropertyChangedCallback(Target)));

    private static void Target(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
    }

}


<Window x:Class="CustomComboBox.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CustomComboBox"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="40" />
        <RowDefinition Height="40" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ComboBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
        <ComboBoxItem>Male</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Female</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>

    <local:ucComboBox x:Name="cmb" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  >
        <local:ucComboBox.ValueList>
            <ComboBoxItem>All</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Male</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Female</ComboBoxItem>
        </local:ucComboBox.ValueList>
    </local:ucComboBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Note that there is a problem with the default value of your ValueList dependency property. You assign `new List<ComboBoxItem>()` as default value, but since the dependency property registration is static, this value is used for *all* instances of your control. You must never assign anything else than `null` as the default value of a reference type dependency property. Instead, assign the default value in the control constructor.

Comment: It is also not necessary to use `List<ComboBoxItem>` as property type. It would be more flexible to use `IEnumerable` instead, since this is the type of the "target" ItemsSource property. You would then be able to assign any kind of collection, e.g. a list of strings.